# cannot detach from SSH secure shell by "ctrl+A+D"

Tags: ssh, superuser

I am new to SSH secure shell
I run a code in a linux server by my PC windows base. Previously when I used "ctrl+A+D", I could be detached from the server and the computation continued no matter what in the server. Now, when I type "ctrl+A+D", I get "^A" and cannot detach too.
what's the problem?

Comment: its question for super user i guess. Recreate it on that. And you will get feedback faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nohup` command to allow a process to run even after the shell is exited.

`SIGHUP` is a signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed. `nohup` runs a command immune to hangups and its usage is as follows.

`nohup <command> &`

It is also important that you redirect `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` for the process.